# Numerically determining steady state in oscillating systems

Tags: energy, oscillators, steady-state

As the title says, I'm trying to determine numerically when an n-DOF oscillating system (linear or nonlinear) subjected to forced base oscillation reaches the steady state solution.

Is there an energy component (or another global parameter) that converges to a single value when the steady state is reached?

I have the time series of the position and velocity of every mass and the base oscillation.